# Statically typed properties in Swift protocols

Tags: swift, oop, model, protocols

I'm trying to use **Protocol-Oriented Pgrogramming** for model layer in my application.

I've started with defining two `protocol`s:

```
protocol ParseConvertible {
    func toParseObject() -> PFObject?
}

protocol HealthKitInitializable {
    init?(sample: HKSample)
}
```

And after implementing first model which conforms to both I've noticed that another model will be basically similar so I wanted to create **protocol inheritance** with new one:

```
protocol BasicModel: HealthKitInitializable, ParseConvertible {

    var value: AnyObject { get set }

}
```

A you can see this `protocol` has one additional thing which is `value` but I want this value to be type independent... Right now I have models which use `Double` but who knows what may show up in future. If I leave this with `AnyObject` I'm sentenced to casting everything I want to use it and if I declare it as `Double` there's no sense in calling this `BasicModel` but rather `BasicDoubleModel` or similar.

Do you have some hints how to achieve this? Or maybe I'm trying to solve this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to define a protocol with an "associated type",
this is roughly similar to generic types.
From ["Associated Types"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189) in the Swift book:

> When defining a protocol, it is sometimes useful to declare one or
>   more associated types as part of the protocol’s definition. An
>   associated type gives a placeholder name (or alias) to a type that is
>   used as part of the protocol. The actual type to use for that
>   associated type is not specified until the protocol is adopted.
>   Associated types are specified with the `typealias` keyword.

In your case:

```
protocol BasicModel: HealthKitInitializable, ParseConvertible {
    typealias ValueType
    var value: ValueType { get set }
}
```

Then classes with different types for the `value` property can
conform to the protocol:

```
class A : BasicModel {
    var value : Int
    func toParseObject() -> PFObject? { ... }
    required init?(sample: HKSample) { ... }
}

class B : BasicModel {
    var value : Double
    func toParseObject() -> PFObject? { ... }
    required init?(sample: HKSample) { ... }
}
```

For **Swift 2.2/Xcode 7.3** and later, replace `typealias` in the
protocol definition by `associatedtype`.